# How to receive notifications when an app goes on sale on Google Play store

Tags: google-play-store, notifications, google-play-wishlist

I would like to know if there's a way to receive notifications on the **computer (online) or smartphone (offline)** when a **customized list** of apps goes on sale on Google Play store. (Maybe through e-mail, RSS feed, SMS, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of this project could be easily developed if there is an available API from Google. I think there is no free `Google API` for this purpose. You can receive `emails` or `SMS` on your mobile phone when a new Android application is published on the Google Play Store, but you need a special API from Google.

Comment: For Android there is an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.tsapps.appsales) that does what I need, but if you need to connect to the internet  to receive notifications, then it's the same as manually checking.
For the iOS there is a [site](http://appshopper.com/iphone/games/prices/paid) that at least allows you to apply some filters and receive notifications through RSS feeds, would be nice to have an Android alternative.
Was hopping to find something even it needs to use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) to combine services.

Comment: I do not think you can combine services, only if you will like to create a web service that maybe helps you for your project.

Comment: Yeah, sites or apps can only interact with [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) if the creators want. I thought about creating something similar to [this](http://www.playstoresales.com/apps/sales/games) but just don't want to create something from scratch because there are already similar options that just need filters and notifications.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, do you like to implement something similar to  the website such as game archives? This could be easy to implement as a software program.

Comment: I have my own website, so as last resort I could probably use the same sources of that [site](http://www.playstoresales.com/apps/sales/games) and make my RSS feed with my filters, to see the apps from my list that go on sale.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I hope that I helped you with your problem of your program.

Comment: Yeah, although I feel that it would be like killing a fly with a bazooka, I will try that option if I can find a place to upload the files like Google Code to avoid changing my website. Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand your logic, but if it works is ok. Thank you.